# Maximizing Google Chrome on Macbook Pro - Can't Search?

Tags: google-chrome, maximize

When I maximize Google Chrome on my MacBook Pro, (SHIFT, COMMAND, F)
I can't see my tabs or search bar on chrome?
Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me  :
Step 1: Copy and paste "chrome://flags/#views-browser-windows" into your browser and hit enter. (do not include quotation marks)

You'll see that it brings you to a page with the text "Use Views browser windows instead of Cocoa." highlighted.

Step 2: Next to it you'll see that it's set to "Default", go ahead and switch that to "Disable".

Step 3: Relaunch Chrome.

[Find here the source](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/9k3evh/no_tabs_bar_when_i_make_chrome_full_screen_on_mac/)

Answer (score -1):

I use the perfect app for controlling sizes of apps on Mac: https://www.spectacleapp.com/.

It also handy to handle the multi-screen system with it.